# How to manually import a gradle dependency in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to contribute to an open source project from Mapzen called "On the Road". ([Github link](https://github.com/mapzen/on-the-road_android))

I would like to edit and add some code to the project. At the moment I'm including the project using gradle with the following dependency:

```
compile 'com.mapzen:on-the-road:1.1.1'
```

Someone gave me a tutorial on how to do this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42188919/how-to-edit-a-gradle-dependency/42188986#42188986), but I'm getting a gradle error;

```
Error:Configuration with name 'default' not found.
```

What I did was clone the project from github, copied the entire master folder into my apps main and renamed it to "customLibrary".

I then added `include':customLibrary'` to my settings.gradle and `compile project(':customLibrary')` to my build.gradle(Module:app) file.

How do I import this project without the errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you cloned the entire master folder, inside the `customLibrary` there is the build.gradle file which is the **top-level file** of the library.

**You can't do it.**

Since you are including the `customLibrary` folder, gradle is looking for a **module** build.gradle.

You have to clone the [library folder](https://github.com/mapzen/on-the-road_android/tree/master/library) instead of the entire master folder.
Otherwise you can use `include':customLibrary:library'` only to add the module library of the entire project.

Comment: When I try this, I get the following error from gradle;`
`Error:(21, 0) No service of type Factory<LoggingManagerInternal> available in ProjectScopeServices.`

this links to ;
`apply plugin: 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven'`

Comment: If anyone is looking for the same answer; I solved it by changing the version of `classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.3.0' ` to 1.4.1 in the build.gradle file from the library.
And then comment out the following line in customLibrary build.gradle file `//classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'`